# Route certain programs to different gateways

Tags: networking, routing, adsl

I own a small network with 15 windows computers, 1 linux server with samba for network storage and 3 aDSL lines of 8Mb/s each. I have set 5 computers in each adsl line. What I want to do, is having one line for web browsing, the other one for games and the last one, as a backup.